# two session_starts() hang PHP app

Tags: php, file, session, front-controller

Context: I was going to build app using mod_rewrite (front page loading child pages), but got stuck on loading session_enabled pages from the front controller page.

Problem: The problem is that I use session_start() call twise, PHP page stops responding. Which is strange, the session_start function is harmless and they are called on different pages.

I've narrowed down the problem to this sample:

child.php file:

> 

parent.php file:

> 

Call to parent.php will make browser load infinitely. As soon as you comment one of session_start() calls - it loads instantly.

What is the source of the problem?
I badly need session-enabled pages.

PS I can work it around by including pages, but they rely on URL params, I would like to avoid fixing them for sake of some kind of parameter proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that only one session can be used at a time. You need to call the [`session_regenerate_id` function](http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id) to generate a new ID:

```
if (session_id() != '') {
    session_write_close();
}
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

Otherwise the parent’s session ID would also be used for the child’s session.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `session_write_close()` once you no longer need to write to the session.  Currently as both your scripts have the session open for their entire duration, you will only be able to have one running at a time.

From [the manua](http://uk.php.net/session_write_close)l:

> Session data is usually stored after
>   your script terminated without the
>   need to call `session_write_close()`,
>   but as session data is locked to
>   prevent concurrent writes only one
>   script may operate on a session at any
>   time. When using framesets together
>   with sessions you will experience the
>   frames loading one by one due to this
>   locking. You can reduce the time
>   needed to load all the frames by
>   ending the session as soon as all
>   changes to session variables are done.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before loading your child page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if a session is already started and only start a new one if not:

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
```

Comment: In this case the session is not started by the same page.

Comment: It looks like the same page, just a different script. I have used this to use the same session in an ajax include on initial page load (when the session is already started as opposed to the ajax call when I need to start the session).

Answer (score 0):

Having two session_starts() in your script is a bad thing anyway.

Why don't you just start the session on your parent.php file (and not child.php)?
Or just child.php and not parent.php

It's a good idea to have one page that is included by all other pages that initializes everything (SQL connect, session start, etc). And then include that page on all others.